# Pass bash variable in yq

Tags: bash, yq

I am trying to pass bash variable in yq

test.yml

```
configuration:
 Properties:
  corporate-url: https://stackoverflow.com/
```

---

```
temp = '.configuration.Properties.corporate-url'
export $temp
Value1=$(yq '.[env($temp)]' test.yml)
```

expected output:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/
```

but I am getting this error(Actual output)

```
Error: Value for env variable '$variable1' not provided in env()
```

**Please note:**
I am trying to fetch corporate-url value, using a bash variable, constraint is that I cannot pass string directly in yq as the value of temp changes as this snippet is running inside a for loop which changes value of temp every time so cannot hard code for a particular value.

**Reference YQ Documentation:**
https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators

**ApisDraft folder contains multiple yml files**

```
ApisDraft=$(find drafts/* -maxdepth 1 -type f)
for ApiFixOrgsTags in $ApisDraft
do
  my_var=$(yq '.securityDefinitions.[].tokenUrl' $ApiFixOrgsTags)
  ConfigProper='.configuration.Properties.'
  CatelogProper='.configuration.catalogs.[].Properties.'
  variable1=$ConfigProper${my_var}
  variable2=$CatelogProper${my_var}
  # to remove white all spaces
  variable1= echo $variable1 | sed -E 's/(\.) */\1/g'
  variable2= echo $variable2 | sed -E 's/(\.) */\1/g'
  export $variable1
  export $variable2
  Value1=$(yq "$variable1" $ApiFixOrgsTags)
  Value2=$(yq '.[env($variable2)]' $ApiFixOrgsTags)
done
```

Comment: sooooo why not just `yq "$temp"`?

Comment: it will result in error

Comment: Your yaml file is broken, it misses a space between `corporate-url:` and `https://stackoverflow.com/`. Then it will work using `temp='.configuration.Properties.corporate-url'; Value1="$(yq "$temp" test.yml)"`

Comment: Please consider it is ok, this is just for explanation purposes, the aim is to find logic

Comment: I made an attempt to reformat this question. If I split anything up incorrectly, please correct. Note that if you put 4 spaces in front of a line in stackoverflow it will format it as code.

Comment: Thank you Jnevil for formatting the question, it looks better

Comment: I agree with @pmf. `Value1=$(yq "$temp" test.yml)` works just fine for me. What error are you getting, or why doesn't that work for your needs?

Comment: Is the second snippet supposed to be bash code? If so, it contains several syntax errors: don't put spaces around `=` in an assignment, and don't use `$` when exporting variables. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting mistakes like these. Also, they should've given you error messages as the script ran; did you get errors?

Comment: Error: Bad expression, please check expression syntax

Comment: I have added the complete code, I don't want to confuse people, please let me know if you have other questions

Comment: No, Gordon just got error for the code: 
 Value1=$(yq "$variable1" $ApiFixOrgsTags)

Comment: Note that `$ApiFixOrgsTags` should itself be in quotes.

Comment: Also, `listOfFiles=$(find ...)` is itself buggy. See [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29); for the better practice alternative, see [Using Find](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind).

Comment: Also, `variable1= echo $variable1 | sed -E 's/(\.) */\1/g'` is not an assignment to `variable1`. See [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you don't need to put it in the environment. Let the shell expand it so yq just sees the *value* of the variable:

```bash
yq "$temp" test.yml     # => https://stackoverflow.com/
```