# How to substitute bash variables into a yq command within a bash function

Tags: bash, yaml, substitution, yq

Say I have an example YAML file, example.yaml:

```
services:
test:
  item0:
  item1:
  item2:
  item3:
```

And I have the follow bash function to recurse through the YAML levels:

```
function readYAML {
    local yaml="$1"
    declare -a arr
    readarray -t arr <<< "$(echo "$yaml" | yq -r '. |select(.) |  keys | .[]' )"
    echo "array -> ${arr[@]}"
    for item in "${arr[@]}"; do
        if [$item != ""]; then
            echo $("'.$item'")
            yq -r "$("'.$item'")" | readYAML;
        fi
    done
}
```

After running

```
readYAML "$(cat example.yaml)"
```

I get a yq error like `'.test': command not found`

**How can I adjust the  `yq -r $("'.$item'") | readYAML;` line so that I end up with an array `arr` that contains `item0` ... `item3`?**

I think that yq is interpreting `$("'.$item'")`  as a command not as a filtering instruction. So I am doing the variable substitution incorrectly somehow.

---

N.B.

i. I know `arr` is overwritten (just stripped out array naming to simplify the question).

ii. I am using Go yq (Mike Farrah v4.31.2)

iii. There are similar questions. But none that I found dealing with substitute bash variables into a yq command within a bash function like this question:

[Pass bash variable in yq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73939413/pass-bash-variable-in-yq)

Answer (score 1):

[Which implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) of yq are you using?

If you are using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), you can make use of the `@sh` builtin from [stedolan/jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) (which is used under the hood) to properly escape the exported strings for shell, and `declare` your array at once:

```bash
$ unset arr; declare -a arr="($(yq -r '.test | keys_unsorted | @sh' example.yaml))"
$ echo "${arr[1]}"
item1
```

[mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) also implemented an `@sh` encoder in the quite recent version v4.31.1, so now you can do the same:

```bash
$ unset arr; declare -a arr="($(yq -r '.test | keys | .[] | @sh' example.yaml))"
$ echo "${arr[1]}"
item1
```

Comment: Thanks this is an improvement to the `readarray` line I think. However, where I'm struggling is in recursively calling the function to get the next level down. In this case in passing `item0: item1:...` etc as an argument to `readYAML`.

Comment: Using mikefarah/yq at the moment btw (question updated)

Comment: @Lee My approach handles the whole array at once, so you wouldn't need a (recursive) function. If you want to do it iteratively, I would still opt for a loop passing in incremented indices for the `keys` array (`bash` is heavily imperative, after all). when using a bash function (even more so in the recursive case) you also have to somehow handle the "returning" of the array wrt scoping and subshells.

Comment: @Lee As a sidenote: If you wanted to "live" in a more declarative-styled shell, have a look at https://www.nushell.sh/. It implements arrays and can natively read YAML. My approach from above would translate to `let arr = (open example.yaml | get test | columns)`, then printing the array would be simply `echo $arr`, and single items just `echo $arr.1`. Also, recursive functions work just as you'd expect them to.